# Import images from HTC to Aperture

Tags: macos, mac, usb, aperture

I have a HTC Desire X and I would like to import the images to Aperture (some are on device, some on card). Unfortunately, the device is not connected as mass storage even when HTC Sync Manager is on.

How do you handle this workflow?

Comment: Can you copy the pictures from your phone onto the Mac in any way?

Comment: @patrix Well, I can uploud them to DropBox one by one, I guess.

Comment: According to the manual, HTC Sync Manager allows batch transfer of photos to your computer (page 10). If this doesn't work in your case, you probably should rewrite your question to ask how you can get that feature to work.

Comment: @patrix Thanks, it works, at least for Windows. Could you transform your comment to an answer? I will accept it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual, HTC Sync Manager allows batch transfer of photos to your computer (page 10).